# jQuery Not to show Year on the Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is it possible not to show the year entry on JQuery UI datepicker?

Now it's shown as **Oct 2010**, but I just need **Oct**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove it via **CSS**, it's probably the simplest solution.

```
.ui-datepicker-year {
    display: none;
}
```

**Tested and works.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the year to be seen, but not selectable, you can do something like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false
});
```